# Is there any method to check if the link, img, script failed to load?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

Here's what I've tried. I believe that onerror don't work for link and script. I am not that sure.

Basically, what I want to achieved is. When the browser failed to load some assets, I am going to reload the webpage. Unluckily, my first step (script) don't work.

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('link'),
    img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    js = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

function chk_error(e){
    for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
        e[i].onerror = function(){
            alert('Failed.'); // doesn't alert even there's error
        }
    }
}

chk_error(link);
chk_error(img);
chk_error(js);
```

AND

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('link, img, script'), function(e){
    e.onerror = function(){
        alert('reload'); // doesn't alert. not working.
    }
});
```

**NOTE:** `I don't use jQuery library with this project.`

Another option is to access the error length in console but I don't know how to get it. And I don't think it is possible by now.

This project is focused on Google Chrome for some reason.

Maybe someone has a better idea or some advice to me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: onerror will be asynchronous, your check (if condition) is synchronous - you'll need to learn the asynchronous coding paradigm

Comment: `javascript` at Question appears to attach error handlers to elements which have already been loaded into document? You can request the resources using `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, if request is successful, append the element to the document, else reload the document

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay :) I'll try to study about it. Wishing I can pull this off. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by putting inline onerror= "location.reload()" to desired img, link, script. I think it is useful also. So, if someone would need the same features. This is how I do it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" onerror="location.reload()">
<img src="images/logo.png" onerror="location.reload();">
<script src="js/tweenmax.js" onerror="location.reload()"></script>
```

Ugly but it worked for me. If someone have a better Idea. Please answer. Thanks.

Edit 2:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('link, img, script'), function(e){
    e.setAttribute('onerror', 'location.reload()');
});
```

Much better than the first one. This will only work if the script is at the top of the head before the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should defined error trigger function before `onerror` has called ! Here in my computer has alert twice because `js/tweenmax.js` and `djffjds.jpg` is not exist .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //this function must be in header tag
    function hasError(argument) {
        alert(argument == 'error');
    }
</script>
<script src="js/tweenmax.js" onerror="hasError('error')"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" onerror="hasError('error')">
<img src="djffjds.jpg" onerror="hasError('error')">
```